# dropdown menu is not working with bootstrap 4 / webpack encore / symfony 4 helppp

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, webpack

I want to use bootstrap dropdowns but it does nothing when I click on it.
I use it with webpack encore.

Here the html :

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('build/css/app.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
```

...

```
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown09"
                   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown09">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**(if i use the 3 links bellow it works, but i want to make it work with app.js)**

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {#<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>#}
    {#<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>#}
    {#<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>#}

    <script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my file webpack.config.js :

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
var Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

Encore
// directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */

    // will create public/build/app.js
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    // will create and public/build/css/app.css
    .addStyleEntry('css/app', ['./assets/css/app.scss'])

    //.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // enable vue.js
    .enableVueLoader()

    // empty the outputPath dir before each build
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

    // show OS notifications when builds finish/fail
    .enableBuildNotifications()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // allow legacy applications to use $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .addPlugin(new Dotenv({
        path: './.env',
        safe: false
    }))

    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
    });
;


module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Here the app.js :

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
```

app.scss :

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
//@import "bootstrap.min.css";
@import "navbar.css";
```

I ran :

```
yarn install
yarn add bootstrap-sass --dev
yarn add bootstrap --dev
yarn add jquery popper.js --dev
yarn run encore dev
```

Please help
Please helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease helpPlease help

Comment: I think you might need to say Please help a few more times. It wasn't clear from the 30 times you already said it.

Comment: Do you see errors in console?

Comment: there are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0):

I found ! We must comment this part in webpack.config.js:

```
// will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
// but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
// .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
```

Comment: While I thank you for your question, I did not need to comment out `.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()` to make Symfony4 + webpack + Bootstrap 4 play nicely together. I did, however, learn there is no way to include KnpMenuBundle in the mix. I've rewritten all my menus the old fashioned way - in html (except for `href` using twig's `path(...)`).